# Can we clean up the [office] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There are 366 questions tagged [office](/questions/tagged/office) at the moment, many of which match [the search "[office] word"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20word). There is already [ms-office](/questions/tagged/ms-office), to which I think these should (in most cases) be retagged, since [office](/questions/tagged/office) is ambiguous (it is used for either Microsoft Office and OpenOffice, and sometimes both).

Convenient searches:

- ["[office] microsoft"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20microsoft) - 117
- ["[office] [microsoft]"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20%5Bmicrosoft%5D) - 22
- ["[office] word"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20word) - 120
- ["[office] [word]"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20%5Bword%5D) - 38
- ["[office] excel"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20excel) - 122
- ["[office] [excel]"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20%5Bexcel%5D) - 68
- ["[office] powerpoint"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20powerpoint) - 26
- ["[office] ppt"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20ppt) - 16
- ["[office] [powerpoint]"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20%5Bpowerpoint%5D) - 9
- ["[office] [macros]"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20%5Bmacros%5D) - 13
- <s>["[office] openoffice"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boffice%5D%20openoffice) (should be retagged to [openoffice.org](/questions/tagged/openoffice.org)).</s> ← Retagging complete.

I think the remainder of the questions under [office](/questions/tagged/office) should then relate to physical offices, i.e. where people work. (The constructivity/on-topic-ness of those questions is dubious IMO, but we won't have a good sense of that until the tag is cleaned up.)

Comment: Can you make a spreadsheet of the questions for us to review? Preferably in Excel.